# GoRoutine: Batch generator doesn't push the left out batch to the output channel

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

When I debug I see the code has generated the left out batch which is `[11,12]` and it should be passed to the output channel via:

```
if len(batch) > 0 { // left out batch with bs < batchsize
    batcher.Output <- batch
    batch = []int{}
}
```

but it seems after the loop.   `for input := range batcher.Input { // listening to the input channel`
nothing is getting executed. Can anyone help me with this?

Remaining batch is not getting passed to the output channel.

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Batcher struct {
    Input  chan int
    Output chan []int
}

func newBatcher() *Batcher {
    return &Batcher{
        Input:  make(chan int),
        Output: make(chan []int),
    }
}

func (batcher *Batcher) generateBatch(batchsize int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    batch := []int{}
    for input := range batcher.Input { // listening to the input channel
        batch = append(batch, input)
        if len(batch) == batchsize {
            batcher.Output <- batch
            batch = []int{}
        }
        // time.Sleep(20 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    if len(batch) > 0 { // left out batch with bs < batchsize
        batcher.Output <- batch
        batch = []int{}
    }
    close(batcher.Output)

}

func usecaseBatcher(inp <-chan int, batcher *Batcher) {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

    // Send inputs from users to the batcher
    go func() {
        for input := range inp {
            batcher.Input <- input
        }
        wg.Done()
        close(batcher.Input)
    }()

    bs := 5

    go batcher.generateBatch(bs, &wg)

    go func() {
        for op := range batcher.Output { // listen to output channel
            fmt.Printf("Output:%v\n", op)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {

    batcher := newBatcher()
    userInp := make(chan int)
    go usecaseBatcher(userInp, batcher)

    // Generate dynamic input
    go sendInput([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, userInp)
    // go sendInput([]int{11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 110, 111}, userInp)

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // Allow some time for processing

    close(userInp)
}

func sendInput(values []int, usersInput chan<- int) {
    for _, value := range values {
        usersInput <- value
    }
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Output:[1 2 3 4 5]
Output:[6 7 8 9 10]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Output:[1 2 3 4 5]
Output:[6 7 8 9 10]
Output:[11 12]
```

EDIT:

Added waiting group still problem persist.

```
func main() {

    batcher := newBatcher()
    userInp := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go usecaseBatcher(userInp, batcher)

    // Generate dynamic input
    go sendInput([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, userInp, &wg)
    // go sendInput([]int{11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 110, 111}, userInp)
    wg.Wait()
    close(userInp)
    // time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // Allow some time for processing

}

func sendInput(values []int, usersInput chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for _, value := range values {
        usersInput <- value
    }
}
```

Comment: Close userInp when sendInput is done

Comment: @BurakSerdar how to do that :( ?
I added `wg.Wait()` before the `close(userInp)` and `defer wg.Done() in sendInput func` but still unable to solve it.

Comment: With a defer close(usersInput) in sendInput

Comment: @BurakSerdar Now it doesn't give me anything after using `defer close(usersInput) in sendInput` in the original(posted) code.

Comment: I got it have to remove `close(userInp)` as we are closing the `userInput` thank you so much for the help.